# Software Manager sometimes says "unable to download firmware updates" from a particular repository

Tags: update-manager, 18.10

When I open Ubuntu Software Manager on my machine, ***sometimes*** it returns this error:

[image: error]

Any idea about it?

I tried to delete the cache:

```
DNSSEC supported by current servers: no

Transactions
Current Transactions: 0
  Total Transactions: 93545

Cache
  Current Cache Size: 4
          Cache Hits: 3598
        Cache Misses: 17357

DNSSEC Verdicts
              Secure: 0
            Insecure: 0
               Bogus: 0
       Indeterminate: 0
```

and tried to change the server, trying different servers from US, Fr, Ch, Italy, and also trying the `select better service` option.

At my eyes, it looks like any server I choose, the IP address remains the same: `151.101.38.49`

`$ ping p2.shared.global.fastly.net`

```
    PING p2.shared.global.fastly.net (151.101.38.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 151.101.38.49 (151.101.38.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=31.7 ms
```

This is my actual config:[image]

[image]

Comment: The DNS system is telling you that it cannot find "cdn.fwupd.org".  You could try `nslookup cdn.fwupd.org` to see if pinging the histname causes the DNS servers to pick up the address for the site, and then opening updates.

Comment: What's the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?  It's just a hunch, but I've seen a similar message when I accidentally made a nonsense edit to that file.

Comment: `$ nslookup cdn.fwupd.org`

```Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
cdn.fwupd.org canonical name = p2.shared.global.fastly.net.
Name: p2.shared.global.fastly.net
Address: 151.101.38.49
```

Comment: Also, trying to change the address, or changing from where to download software, (US, CH, FR, I) the result is always the same
151.101.38.49 !!!!!
`$ ping p2.shared.global.fastly.net`

```PING p2.shared.global.fastly.net (151.101.38.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.38.49 (151.101.38.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=31.7 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

As you say "sometimes** it returns this error"
It may be intermittent fault in your ISP server or site server.
Run `ping cdn.fwupd.org` whenever you have the fault.This should be something like

```
ping cdn.fd.org
ping: cdn.fd.org: Name or service not known
```

otherwise

```
ping cdn.fwupd.org
PING p2.shared.global.fastly.net (151.101.194.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.194.49 (151.101.194.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=44.8 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.194.49 (151.101.194.49): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=44.3 ms
```

If Software Manger shows error and ping is ok we can pssiblly **try** Software Manager server configuration.
To open Software & Updates run `software-properties-gtk` in  terminal.
In "Ubuntu Software" tab. Choosing some other server as shown below might help.

[image: Software Manger]

or maybe in Software & Update>Other Software>Canonical Partners is not selected. As below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

1. Run `sudo apt update` to reload the list of software sources
2. If `fwupd` is not installed, install it using `sudo snap install fwupd`
3. Restart the computer
4. Open Ubuntu Software; the message should be gone

If the message is still there, you can try this:

1. Open Software & Updates (in 19.10 it's a white A on a blue background)
2. Select "Other" in [the "Choose a server" dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mif3X.png)
3. Click [the "Select Best Server" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydDPa.png)
4. When [the dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4YkQ.png) closes, click the "Reload" button in [the dialog asking about reloading the software information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTmfT.png)
5. Restart the computer