# Issue with Ubuntu Software

Tags: updates

Ubuntu Software is telling me that it is 'Unable to download firmware updates from "fwupd": failed to download https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.asc: Cannot resolve hostname'.

[image: Ubuntu Software]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software Manager sometimes says "unable to download firmware updates" from a particular repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123521/software-manager-sometimes-says-unable-to-download-firmware-updates-from-a-par)